# Update jsonb set new value select from the same table

Tags: postgresql

i have a table `foo`:

```
    id | items
    ---+--------------------------------
     1 |{"item_1": {"status": "status_1"}}
     2 |{"item_2": {"status": "status_2"}}
     ...
```

I need to update all rows in column `items` which is a jsonb and set after `{"status": "status"}` new values (`"new_value": "new_value"`) and after update the result must look like this:

```
    id | items
    ---+------------------------------------------------------------
     1 |{"item_1": {"status": "status_1", "new_value": "new_value"}}
     2 |{"item_2": {"status": "status_2", "new_value": "new_value"}}
     ...
```

i've tried to do this:

```
WITH result AS (
    INSERT INTO foo (id, items)
        SELECT id, options || newvalue as res
        FROM foo AS bar,
             jsonb_each(bar.items::jsonb) AS item,
             to_jsonb(item.value) AS options,
             jsonb_build_object('new_value', 'new_value') as newvalue
        WHERE id IN ('1', '2'...)
        ON CONFLICT (id)
            DO UPDATE
                SET items = foo.items || Excluded.items::jsonb RETURNING *)
SELECT item.key AS itemkey
FROM result AS res,
     jsonb_each(res.items) AS item,
     to_jsonb(item.value) AS options;
```

but when i run this script the postgres shows this error message:

```
on conflict do update command cannot affect row a second time postgres
```

i dont understand what am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE#1**

Postgres version 9.6
table `foo id = TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL`
about why `INSERT` but not just `UPDATE`? the answer is this is my mistake first mistake.

Comment: It means that your `id`s in the rows to be inserted are not unique, probably caused by `jsonb_each`.

Comment: Please start by disclosing table definition and Postgres version. And why is there an `INSERT` if you only want to *update*?

Comment: i ve written in update block

Comment: just execute the SELECT on it's own. Do you have duplicated rows? If yes, you have to deduplicate (make them unique) first, before. That's what the error means

Comment: I check it, there is no dublicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some reading postgres functions finally i find out:

```
UPDATE foo as t
SET items = result.new_value
FROM (SELECT st.id, new_value
      FROM foo AS st
               CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
          SELECT jsonb_object_agg(the_key, the_value || '{"new_value": "some_new_value"}'::jsonb) AS new_value
          FROM jsonb_each(st.items) AS x(the_key, the_value)
          LIMIT 1) AS n) AS result
WHERE result.id = t.id;
```